# Correct installation of config.h for shared library using autotools

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, autotools, autoconf, libtool

I am converting a C++ program which uses the autotools build system to use a shared library, introducing the use of libtool. Most of the program functionality is being placed in the shared library, which is loaded by the main program, so that the common code can be accessed by other programs in future.

Throughout the program and library sources the autoheader generated `config.h` is used with the usual macro:

```
#if HAVE_CONFIG_H
# include <config.h>
#endif
```

In configure.ac I use the macro to generate it:

```
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
```

My question is, do I need to install `config.h` for others to be able to use my library, and if so, what is the appropriate way to do it, and should it be renamed to avoid conflicts etc?

The most information I have found on this is here:

http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/building_libraries/building_libraries#installingheaders

But this is hardly an official source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install `config.h` if it affects the *interface*. In practical terms, if the `#define`'s are required by the header(s), not just the `.cc` implementation / compilation units.

If `config.h` is a problem, you can specify another name in the [AC_CONFIG_HEADERS](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Configuration-Headers) macro. e.g., `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([foo_config.h])`.

The easiest way to install the header, assuming [automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Headers), is with:

`nodist_include_HEADERS = foo_config.h`

in the top-level `Makefile.am`. the `nodist` prefix tells automake that `foo_config.h` is generated rather than distributed with the package.

If not using automake, install `foo_config.h` in `$includedir`. `$exec_prefix/include` is arguably a more *correct* location for a generated header, but in practice the former location is fine.

---

I avoid using `config.h`, by passing relevant definitions in `CPPFLAGS` or `foo_CPPFLAGS` along with `AC_SUBST` to `Makefile.am` for source builds, or `AC_SUBST` to `foo.h.in` to generate headers at configure-time. A lot of `config.h` is test-generated noise. It requires more infrastructure, but it's what I prefer. I wouldn't recommend this approach unless you're comfortable with the autotools.

Comment: if I just change the name, and not the actual definitions in foo-config.h is this likely to ever be a problem?

Comment: @crobar - I don't think so. `autoheader` (or `autoreconf`) should honour the `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS` name to produce `foo_config.h.in`; and configure should use this template to generate `foo_config.h`.

Comment: I'm working on an existing project, it uses throughout it things like nr_double_t for double as defined in config.h. In fact I've realized my headers do not require this. I'll mark your answer correct, but just add that others might be interested in the m4 macro `AX_PREFIX_CONFIG_H`, which also changes all the definitions in the config file to be unique to your project. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Never **ever** install autoheader's `config.h`.

The last thing the users of your library need is interference from the macros leaking out of your `config.h`. Your library may have `HAVE_FOOBAR`, but my software might be compiled in a way that **foobar** is disabled, so that `HAVE_FOOBAR` will break my compilation.

The [AX_PREFIX_CONFIG macro from the archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prefix_config_h.html) is a workaround, where everything gets prefixed.

A better approach is to create a template file (e.g. `blargconfig.h.in`) with lines like:

```
typedef @BLARG_TYPE@ blarg_int_t;

@BLARG_RANDOM_INCLUDE@
```

And then `AC_SUBST()` those variables in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_SUBST(BLARG_TYPE, ["unsigned short"])
AC_SUBST(BLARG_RANDOM_INCLUDE, ["#include <somerandomheader.h>"])
```

Then list it as an output file:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
                 src/Makefile
                 ...
                 include/blargconfig.h])
```

The `.h` file should be listed with `nodist_include_HEADERS`; the `.h.in` file will be automatically distributed because it's listed in `AC_CONFIG_FILES`.

Destination for such files is commonly `$libdir/packagename/include`. Example: GLib, before they switched to meson:

```
# From glib-2.53.1/glib/Makefile.am:
#
# Generate glibconfig.h
#
# The timestamp of the stamp file is used to indicate if glibconfig.h is
# up to date with respect to config.status.  In the usual case, changes
# to config.status will not result in changes to glibconfig.h so we
# avoid touching its timestamp (in order not to rebuild the whole tree).
#
DISTCLEANFILES += glibconfig-stamp glibconfig.h glibconfig.h.win32
BUILT_SOURCES += glibconfig-stamp
configexecincludedir = $(libdir)/glib-2.0/include
nodist_configexecinclude_HEADERS = glibconfig.h
glibconfig-stamp: ../config.status
        $(AM_V_GEN) cd $(top_builddir) && \
          $(SHELL) ./config.status glib/glibconfig.h
        $(AM_V_GEN) cd $(top_builddir) && \
          $(SHELL) ./config.status glib/glibconfig.h.win32
        @touch glibconfig-stamp
```

Note that they generate `glibconfig.h` without a template, by invoking `config.status`; the generation code originates from `configure.ac`:

```
dnl From glib-2.53.1/configure.ac:
dnl
dnl this section will only be run if config.status is invoked with no
dnl arguments, or with "glib/glibconfig.h" as an argument.
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([glib/glibconfig.h],
[
        outfile=glib/glibconfig.h-tmp
        cat > $outfile <<\_______EOF
/* glibconfig.h
 *
 * This is a generated file.  Please modify 'configure.ac'
 */

#ifndef __GLIBCONFIG_H__
#define __GLIBCONFIG_H__

#include <glib/gmacros.h>
(...etc...)
        if cmp -s $outfile glib/glibconfig.h; then
          AC_MSG_NOTICE([glib/glibconfig.h is unchanged])
          rm -f $outfile
        else
          mv $outfile glib/glibconfig.h
        fi
],[
dnl commands to set the environment variables used during output
])
```

This is what [the autobook suggests](https://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_66.html#Installing-Header-Files), though its examples are failing to render. I find this approach less maintainable than using `AC_SUBST`, but it's more flexible.

Of course, to help the compiler find the platform-dependent header you'll probably also want to write a pkgconfig script, like GLib does.

Comment: Thanks, it's curious to me that the whole process has not been anticipated by the autotools developers, it must come up quite often.

Comment: @crobar In a small statistic of 14 libraries that distributed a config.h I saw 9 of them renaming it, and 4 including it.

Comment: `compiler find the platform-dependent header you'll probably also want to write a pkgconfig script` could you be more specific, please? I would like to search existing library for platform (configure) dependent header files.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you creating a library that needs to install such headers, or are you trying to find such headers? The tool I mentioned, `pkg-config`, is just a way to hide all the magic required in order to use the library. Try `man pkg-config`, or Google.