# Disabling cxx support for libtool after calling AC_PROG_CXX

Tags: c++, configure, autotools, automake, libtool

For my project (library), I use configure with libtool and automake to build under linux hosts. The library consists of a C API, as well as an optional C++ extension. So, since
AC_PROG_CXX must be called globally, I use automake conditionals:

```
*configure.ac*:

AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_CXX
AM_PROG_AR

LT_INIT

... some tests to figure out 'build_cxx' ...

AC_CONDITIONAL([CXX], [ test x$build_cxx = xyes ])
```

And inside Makefile.am

```
sources = files.c
if CXX then
   cxx_sources = files.cpp
else
   cxx_sources =
endif

sources = $sources $cxx_sources
```

The whole thing, however, does not work when configure is not able to locate g++ (which practically kills the extra logic for the c++ extension). After some research, I've come down to the conclusion that AC_PROG_CXX somehow tells libtool to assume that c++ support. I was also surprised to realise that if AC_PROG_CXX fails, it sets CXX to 'g++'!!!

Anyway, calling AC_PROG_CXX conditionally  produces errors like 'am_fastdepCXX is never defined', which seems logical to me. The worst thing is that the error is not shown while configure is running, but it appears later in the linking phase, in to form of 'unknown libtool option `-o`' (ouch).

The full source code can be found here -> http://bitbucket.org/sdlu/sdlu/src

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Automake limitation, it doesn't care about the condition when choosing the linker.

One work-around is to conditionally rewrite the _LINK command, as suggested in [this mailing list post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/libtool/2009-04/msg00050.html):

```
if USE_CXX
    cxx_sources = ...
else
    cxx_sources =
    libSDLU_la_LINK = $(LINK) $(libSDLU_la_CFLAGS) $(libSDLU_la_LDFLAGS)
endif
```

Another way (suggested in the same discussion) is to put the C++ sources in a utility library that is built and added conditionally, then added to the main library:

```
if CXX
    noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libSDLUxx.la
    libSDLUxx_la_SOURCES =  src/cxx/SDLU_CButton.cxx \
                            src/cxx/SDLU_CIniHandler.cxx \
                            src/cxx/SDLU_CRenderer.cxx \
                            src/cxx/SDLU_CSprite.cxx \
                            src/cxx/SDLU_CTexture.cxx \
                            src/cxx/SDLU_CWindow.cxx
    libSDLU_la_LIBADD = libSDLUxx.la
endif
```

---

## Some unrelated notes

1. Do not put generated files (`Makefile.in`, `configure`, etc) into source control.
2. Add a `bootstrap` script that invokes the autotools to generate things.
3. Prefer pkg-config (i.e. `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(SDL2, sdl2)`) over hand-crafted autoconf macros (i.e. `AM_PATH_SDL2`);
4. Do not install autoheaders (i.e. `SDLU_config.h.in`). It makes your library incompatible with every autoconf-based software, as you are re-defining `PACKAGE`, `VERSION`, and all library-detection macros. See [my answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586211/correct-installation-of-config-h-for-shared-library-using-autotools) for examples on how to do it.
5. I would have the C++ API built and installed as an independent, optional library; drop the sdlu-config script altogether, then write `sdluxx.pc` that requires `sdlu`. Do not bother checking if the C++ compiler works, if the user passed `--enable-cxx` he knows what he's doing; I prefer to have the build fail than silently have an incomplete library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the first work-around (changing the LINK command) worked perfectly for me. As for the notes:

Comment: **1-2**: I chose to add the generated files in order to avoid the common issue with different incompatible versions of the autotools **3**: These macros internally use pkg-config and fallback to the appropriate scripts (sdl2-config) **4**: This is fixed in the latest version, thanks for noting **5**: I would like to avoid that and use it only as a last resort, mainly because I also maintain build systems based on CMake and premake. Thanks again!

Comment: Still, generated files don't belong to the repository. When you do a "make dist-gzip" to create a tarball, everything will be packaged so the user doesn't need autoconf/automake installed. I'm one of the ODE maintainers, if you want to have a look at our repo: http://sourceforge.net/p/opende/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/

Comment: I know what you say, but I hand-edit the generated Makefile.in a little bit, so have it packed automatically is not really an option. Plus, I prefer repository clones from tarballs, but then again, I prefer eggs over bacon...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to interfere in the handling of the CXX variable.

Use your own variable BUILD_CXX

```
AC_CONDITIONAL([BUILD_CXX], [ test x$build_cxx = xyes ])here
```

and

```
if BUILD_CXX
  # ....
endif
```

Comment: No, this isn't the problem... Using CXX works perfectly as a conditional name