# Optional source code generation using Autotools (C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, autotools

I have a header file named `api.h` which contains my library's public functions. I would like the function `void func_xxx();` to be declared in `api.h` only if the user enables it using `./configure --enable-xxx`. Is this possible? Ideally I do not want to use `#ifdef` for this? I know how to implement the `--enable-xxx` flag in my `configure.ac` script but I do not know how to add the function declaration to `api.h` if `--enable-xxx` is used.

Thanks for your help

Comment: why do you want to avoid `#ifdef` for that, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: My goal is that the user does not need to use -DHAVE_XXX in order to compile his program.

Comment: he doesn't, though. autotools will take care of that. unless I misunderstood you =)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will take a closer look at this.

Comment: I see that I can achieve what I want if I include config.h in api.h? (But this is normally not advised!?). Other than this I still have no idea how to do it i.e. gcc -c program.c fails if program.c includes api.h and uses func_xxx().

Comment: do you have a source as to why it is not advised to include config.h? Including this file is the main method of communication between autotools and the C code.

Comment: Here are two sources for not installing config.h: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19694763/363778, http://inaugust.com/post/68. The first link also describes a work around which I might use.

Comment: quoting from your source "config.h should ALWAYS be the first thing included by EVERY non-header C/C++ file in your project." including and installing are two different things =) EDIT: I totally misunderstood your question, sorry. I did not get that you want to change an installed header file at library compile time. my bad.

Comment: in recent versions of autotools preprocessor defines are usually set by configure setting variables like, CPPFLAGS, AM_CPPFLAGS, target_CPPFLAGS etc. you don't need to use config.h

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not good practice because, as you mentioned, you would need `#if`preprocessor macros, dragging `config.h` to the public interface, and hence, having to install it. Config files are not meant to be installed.

I suggest that you do that at runtime, this is suggested practice in books like [API design for C++](http://www.apibook.com/blog/), a very recommende read, by the way:

```
bool isFuncXXXEnabled();
void funcxxx();
```

Your code:

```
if (isFuncXXXEnabled()) {
}
else {
}
```

In your .cpp file you can disable the body of the function, because `config.h will not be exposed in the public interface.

Comment: Good answer. Other than "config files are not meant to be installed", a reason to do it this way is that if your `api.h` can change depending on how someone configured the library, then programs that work fine on one system could fail to compile on another (or, if they were installed as binary packages through a package manager, they could crash!)

Comment: Well, that is true, but I think there is a tradeoff here. The standard solution is that, AFAIK. Without depending on the config you should do much more complicated machinery like machine-generating an api.h file from an api.h.in, without #ifdefs, at the time of generating. You could do this replacing autoconf variables or similar, but I don't know how good this idea would be.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your answer, it completely decouples my API from the user's code. Another less optimal solution is to create an installable config file using the ax_prefix_config_h.m4 macro from http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prefix_config_h.html

Comment: "but I don't know how good this idea would be.". It is not a good idea e.g. if I build my library using compiler A and the user compiles his code using compiler B then his code might break because api.h has been built specifically for compiler A (e.g. api.h might use non standard extensions from compiler A).